# WPF MVVM DataGrid RowDetails with different ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, itemssource, rowdetailstemplate

I have three `DataGrids` set up as individual `UserControls` with each `ItemsSource` bound to a different `DependencyProperty` in my `ViewModel`.
When a row is selected in the first `DataGrid`, the other two populate with information relevant to the selected row. Though this works fine, I want the second and third `DataGrid` to be displayed in the `RowDetailsTemplate` of the first `DataGrid`.

The issue I am having is that the `ItemsSource` of the parent `DataGrid` is overriding that of the other two, so they are not populating. I have tried solutions posted on many other similar questions but none have solved my problem. My code is below, I'm hoping that I've just missed something obvious but any help would be appreciated!

### Main Datagrid

```
<DataGrid x:Name="PostDataGrid" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding WSEDriverList}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedWSEDriverPOST}"
              Style="{DynamicResource MainDataGridStyle}"
              Margin="0,0,0,0"
              Grid.Row="1" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="HesId"             Binding="{Binding HESID,            Mode=OneWay}"                 Width="50"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="WseId"             Binding="{Binding WSEID,            Mode=OneWay}"                 Width="50"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="API"               Binding="{Binding API,              Mode=OneWay}"                 Width="198" />
            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Request Date"      Binding="{Binding Path=REQUEST_DATE, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat=dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}" Width="125"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Result Date"       Binding="{Binding Path=RESULT_DATE,  Mode=OneWay, StringFormat=dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}" Width="125"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Return Code"       Binding="{Binding RETURN_CODE,      Mode=OneWay,  StringFormat=0}" Width="80" />
            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Status"            Binding="{Binding STATUS,           Mode=OneWay,  StringFormat=0}" Width="70" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:WSEAuditViewModel}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Expander Header="NOTIFICATION" Grid.Row="0">
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding WSEDriverGETResult}">
                            <usercontrol:NOTIFICATIONUserControl/>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </Expander>
                    <Expander Header="GET" Grid.Row="1">
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding WSEDriverGETResult}">
                            <usercontrol:GETUserControl/>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </Expander>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
```

### DataGrid 2 (NOTIFICATIONUserControl)

```
<DataGrid x:Name="NotificationDG" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding NotificationResult}"
```

### DataGrid 3 (GETUserControl)

```
<DataGrid x:Name="GetDG" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding WSEDriverGETResult}"
```

### Edit

Here is the code for my `DependencyProperties` bound to my `DataGrid`.

```
//----POST result list from WSE_DRIVER-----
    public List<WSE_DRIVER> WSEDriverList
    {
        get { return (List<WSE_DRIVER>)GetValue(WSEDriverListProperty); }
        set { SetValue(WSEDriverListProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty WSEDriverListProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("WSEDriverList",
                                    typeof(List<WSE_DRIVER>),
                                    typeof(WSEAuditViewModel),
                                    new PropertyMetadata(WSEDriverListChanged_Callback));

    private static void WSEDriverListChanged_Callback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        WSEAuditViewModel wse_win = (WSEAuditViewModel)d;
        if (wse_win.WSEDriverList.Count > 0)
        {
            wse_win.SelectedWSEDriverPOST = wse_win.WSEDriverList.First();
        }

    }

    //----Selected POST WSE_Driver----
    public WSE_DRIVER SelectedWSEDriverPOST
    {
        get { return (WSE_DRIVER)GetValue(SelectedWSEDriverPOSTProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedWSEDriverPOSTProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedWSEDriverPOSTProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedWSEDriverPOST",
                                    typeof(WSE_DRIVER),
                                    typeof(WSEAuditViewModel),
                                    new PropertyMetadata(SelectedWSEDriverPOSTChanged_Callback));

    private static void SelectedWSEDriverPOSTChanged_Callback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
          //Gets list and assigns to WSEDriverGETResult and NotificationResult
    }



    //----GET result from WSE_Driver----
    public List<WSE_DRIVER> WSEDriverGETResult
    {
        get { return (List<WSE_DRIVER>)GetValue(WSEDriverGETResultProperty); }
        set { SetValue(WSEDriverGETResultProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty WSEDriverGETResultProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("WSEDriverGETResult",
                                    typeof(List<WSE_DRIVER>),
                                    typeof(WSEAuditViewModel),
                                    new PropertyMetadata(WSEDriverGETResultChanged_Callback));

    private static void WSEDriverGETResultChanged_Callback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }



    //----Notification Info----
    public List<SPEC_NOTIFICATION> NotificationResult
    {
        get { return (List<SPEC_NOTIFICATION>)GetValue(NotificationResultProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NotificationResultProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty NotificationResultProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("NotificationResult",
                                    typeof(List<SPEC_NOTIFICATION>),
                                    typeof(WSEAuditViewModel),
                                    new UIPropertyMetadata(NotificationResultChanged_Callback));

    private static void NotificationResultChanged_Callback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Comment: So where is the NotificationResult property defined?

Comment: My dependency properties have callbacks that deal with the selection change (I am new to wpf so assuming that's what you mean?)

Comment: Post your code if you want anyone to be able to help you. You are trying to bind to some property called NotificationResult. How is anyone supposed to know anything about this property?

Comment: Apologies, I mis-read your comment. Will update with the full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `NotificationResult` and `WSEDriverGETResult` properties belong to the same class as the `WSEDriverList` property, you should be able to use a `{RelativeSource}` to bind to the `DataContext` of the parent `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="NotificationDG" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.NotificationResult, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"></DataGrid>
```

---

```
<DataGrid x:Name="GetDG" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.WSEDriverGETResult, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"></DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried something very similar before but I set the AncestorType as UserControl instead!

Comment: The reference structure worked well.  I had tried an acestor of  UserControl and DataGird, but eventually what worked was DataGridRow.
`<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
 <DataTemplate>
  <local:ucExpensesSummary DataSource="{Binding DataContext.ExpenseItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"></local:ucExpensesSummary>
 </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>`